# Stream.Write uses UT16 instead of UTF8

Tags: c#, stream

we got some process that takes a text file (with a list of directories) and saves it into a dat file.
it takes all lines from a txt file, converts them into a byte[], and saves them as a dat file.

the format is [size_of_file] [num_of_lines][list_of_directories]

for example: [12 0 0 0][1 0 0 0][92 0 97 0 ....]

Now, we got another process that is invoking a rest API that streams this dat file , and converts it into a text file again.

The problem:
when I take a text file with 1 line the process that convert the stream is creating the text file as a UTF-16 LE, while if the file has more than 1 line it will create it as a UTF-8

the code:

```
    public static void ExtractDatFileData(string datFilePath)
    {
        // Open DAT file as stream
        var info = new FileInfo(datFilePath);
        var stream = info.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        // Write stream into "data.dat" file (creates a copy to read that data from it)
        var inputFile = Path.Combine(@"C:\demo\data.dat");
        using (var file = File.OpenWrite(inputFile))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(file);
        }

        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
        {
            // Read the size of the file
            int bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, 4);
            int fileSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);

            // Read data from the DAT file
            while (input.Position < input.Length)
            {


                // --- directories list ---
                var dirTxtPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\demo\directories.txt");
                using (Stream output = File.Create(dirTxtPath))
                {
                    int remaining = fileSize;
                    while (remaining > 0 && (bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(remaining, BUFFER_SIZE))) > 0)
                    {
                        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        remaining -= bytesRead;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, this is the problematic code:

```
                var dirTxtPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\demo\directories.txt");
                using (Stream output = File.Create(dirTxtPath))
                {
                    int remaining = fileSize;
                    while (remaining > 0 && (bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(remaining, BUFFER_SIZE))) > 0)
                    {
                        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        remaining -= bytesRead;
                    }
                }
```

it seems that `output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);` will write as utf-16 or utf-8 in different scenarios, but I'm not sure how it decided how to create the file encoding.

Things I've done:

I made sure that when writing the original DAT file it does the same code for 1 line or more. i double checked it, and then re-double checked it :)

I inspected both DAT files that were created using a compare tool (Beyond Compare) and it seems that the data is in the same format

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: Bytes are bytes. If you copy bytes, the encoding stays the same. Explain why you suspect what your observe.

Comment: "it seems that output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); will write as utf-16 or utf-8 in different scenarios," - to echo what @CodeCaster said: it isn't even *trying* to think in terms of UTF-*anything*; you're *just* dealing with bytes here, and those bytes are being copied as-is. Was it your intention to normalize the encoding? Note that this is difficult if you don't explicitly and reliably know the input encoding of every individual file, since most text files don't include a BOM (and code-page encodings don't even have BOMs defined)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `StreamWriter` to write text data according to your needs.

```cs
using (TextWriter w = new StreamWriter(outputFile, false, Encoding.ASCII)) // Or whatever encoding you need.
{
   //...
   w.Write("SomeString"); // This converts the (unicode) String to the encoding provided above.
}
```

In your code, you're copying the text as raw, binary data. Depending on the input file format, it may be prepended by a byte order mark, which, in turn, will be copied to the output, causing the output file to get a different format as well.

Comment: I believe it is the *intention* of the OP to be writing binary here; that doesn't look accidental; and if it is: ASCII is almost never the right answer

Comment: @MarcGravell He's writing about writing text files line-by-line, which doesn't make sense with raw binary data. I didn't understand what format he wants, though.

Comment: They're talking about text files and lines, but they're reading and writing bytes. No encoding involved there.